# Value of variable not changing in observeSingleEvent

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

The variable num changes to what I want inside the observeSingleEvent, but just after it changes back to an empty value. How do i get the value of num to change??

```
   var num = Int()
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

    print(snap)

    if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

        self.num = snapDict["date"] as! Int
        print(num)
        //returns the number I want

    }
    })

    print(num)
    //Returns an empty value

    if num == 5 {
        print("number is 5")
    else {
        print("number is not 5")
        //goes to this
     }
```

Comment: To also get changes to the data, use `observeEventOfType` instead of `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you so much!

Comment: The reason that your second `print(num)` is an empty value is because Firebase is asynchronous. The last print executes before the print within the completion handler.

Comment: @dstepan I want to use the num variable for an if statement after I get the value from the database. How would I do that if it's asynchronous?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Any work that you need to do with values that are coming back from Firebase must be done within the completion handler (the `with` part of the method call). To use/manipulate the `num` value you get from Firebase, you need to use it within your completion handler.

```
var num = Int()

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

    print(snap)

    if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

        self.num = snapDict["date"] as! Int

        if self.num == 5 {
            print("number is 5")
        else {
            print("number is not 5")
        }
    }
})
```